# mypy: Value of type "Optional[Mapping[Any, Any]]" is not indexable

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Why does `mypy` say that the value returned by the `fetch_one` method of the `databases` library is not indexable? What should I do in this case to resolve this error?

```
async def get_reaction_by_name(name: str, user_id: str) -> Optional[Mapping[Any, Any]]:
    query = reactions.select().where(
        (reactions.c.name == name) & (reactions.c.user_id == user_id)
    )
    return await database.fetch_one(query)

...

reaction = await get_reaction_by_name(name=name, user_id=user_id)
reaction["name"]

# mypy: Value of type "Optional[Mapping[Any, Any]]" is not indexable
```

Comment: what is the signature of `database.fetch_one` function?

Comment: also since it is `Optional` mypy says that you probably should check if the returned value is not `None` before treating it like a `Mapping`

Comment: something like `if reaction is not None: reaction["name"]`

Comment: Check for `None` helped! Please add an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What mypy says us is that since function returns `Optional[...]` before treating its result as a `...` (`Mapping[Any, Any]` in given snippet) we should check whether it's not a `None` like

```py
reaction = await get_reaction_by_name(name=name, user_id=user_id)
if reaction is not None:
    reaction["name"]
```